# Disable Finder icon preview blurring

Tags: finder, graphics

When I click on a finder icon to view it's preview, the icon is crystal clear like in this photo,

[image: Clear icon]

But when I scroll through all the files with the arrow keys after I click, they become blurred like this:

[image]

Is there any way to disable this or is there an app the stops this?

Comment: does it becomes more clear if you wait a moment? does it only do that with specific files (icons)

Comment: No it's permanently blurry. As far as i know, it does it with all png and psd files. They are small in dimensions (pixel art) so with larger pictures it might look good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've finally found the reason why it's been doing this. Every time you click the item it generates a preview the very moment you click down on the item. During the period that your mouse is clicked down, it runs its image anti-aliasing algorithms to create the preview.

I've noticed when I click on the item as fast as I can (ensure that I release the click as fast as possible), I get a better probability of the image being aliased rather than smoothed. Being a programmer, I think it's definitely because the computer can't generate the smoothed preview fast enough if a fast click is used. So to always get aliased images, I'd think a macro is probably the only way to click fast enough without having to rely on the speed of your finger every time you click.

(usually you can set the execution time of the macro, this is the only thing I can think of to solve the problem)